# How does | and + do the trick to turn string into number?

Tags: javascript

When I was reading a [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Symbol_type_conversions) about Symbol on MDN, I noticed these things can trun string into number which I've never seen before.

Quote:

> When trying to convert a symbol to a number, a TypeError will be
>   thrown (e.g. +sym or sym | 0).

For example:

```
+"15"
```

will return

```
15
```

which is number type.

Also

```
"15" | 0
```

can do the same thing.

I am wondering how does this trick work.
Can you help?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()

Comment: `"15"+` is meaningless on its own. The unary `+` operator comes before its operand. `+"15" === 15` is `true`. `"15"+ === 15` is a syntax error.

Comment: @Paulpro Sorry for the mistake. Corrected it.

Comment: They are not the same. `+a` convert a to Double (64 bit IEEE 754 float), `a|0` convert a to Int32 (32 bit signed integer). Btw, `a>>>0` convert a to Uint32 (32 bit unsigned integer).

Comment: @tsh they both convert to ieee754 double, but the latter additionally truncates it to 32 bits integer (but still represented as a double)

Comment: @zerkms `a|0` first convert it to Int32. And depends on the context, it may be converted to Double later, and may be represented as Int32 for better performance. asm.js do act such optimize and use `+a`, `a|0` as type declaration.

Comment: Unary `+` operator works as described in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-unary-plus-operator), as does the bitwise OR (`|`) [operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-binary-bitwise-operators-static-semantics-isfunctiondefinition) .

Comment: @tsh javascript does not have integer numeric types, all numbers are ieee754 doubles. https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unary Plus Operator**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()

> The unary plus operator precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to convert it into a number, if it isn't already. Although unary negation (-) also can convert non-numbers, unary plus is the fastest and preferred way of converting something into a number, because it does not perform any other operations on the number. It can convert string representations of integers and floats, as well as the non-string values true, false, and null. Integers in both decimal and hexadecimal ("0x"-prefixed) formats are supported. Negative numbers are supported (though not for hex). If it cannot parse a particular value, it will evaluate to NaN.

```
+"6";//6
+6;//6
+-6;//-6
+undefined;//NaN
+false;//0
+true;//1
+null;//0
+{};//NaN
+[];//0
+function(){};//NaN
```

**Bitwise OR Operator**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7c_%28Bitwise_OR%29

> The operands are converted to 32-bit integers and expressed by a series of bits (zeroes and ones). Numbers with more than 32 bits get their most significant bits discarded. 
>   Each bit in the first operand is paired with the corresponding bit in the second operand: first bit to first bit, second bit to second bit, and so on.
>   The operator is applied to each pair of bits, and the result is constructed bitwise.

The Bitwise OR Operator first converts both operands to 32-bit integers and each bit is compared. When comparing the two bits, if any of the bits is 1, 1 is returned. If both bits are 0, 0 is returned.

Example:

```
2|1;//produces 3
--------
00000010   //2 in binary
00000001   //1 in binary
--------
00000011   //3 in binary
```

Answer (score 1):

`+"15"` is casting the `"15"` to a number type, the same way `-15` works.

eg.

```
>> -"15" === -15
>> true
```

The second case, `"15" | 0` is doing the same thing, casting to an integer in order to perform a [Bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators).

Which means taking the bits of 15 and ORing them with the bits of zero.

`15` in binary is, for example `00001111` and zero is `00000000` so each bit is or'd with each other resulting in `15` again which is returned.